# Is it possible to distinguish between a bluetooth headset and bluetooth car kit?

Tags: android, bluetooth

My problem is this: "Is it possible to know if a user is using a bluetooth car kit rather than a headset?"  I only want certain features to work if the user is on a car kit.  Is this possible?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using device class (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.html( use method getDeviceClass() and getMajorDeviceClass()), this can help you to know if the peer device is a carkit or not(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.html#AUDIO_VIDEO_CAR_AUDIO)